# Assamese fonts are incorrectly visible in ubuntu 14 or 16

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, fonts

The `assamese` font is incorrectly rendered in Chrome and Firefox. I think its taking it as Bengali instead.

This is an example of incorrect fonts:

[image]

This is an example of the correct font:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the order of precedence which fontconfig provides on my machine:

```
$ fc-match -a | grep -i lohit
Lohit-Bengali.ttf: "Lohit Bengali" "Regular"
Lohit-Gujarati.ttf: "Lohit Gujarati" "Regular"
Lohit-Punjabi.ttf: "Lohit Punjabi" "Regular"
Lohit-Assamese.ttf: "Lohit Assamese" "Regular"
Lohit-Devanagari.ttf: "Lohit Devanagari" "Regular"
```

I added this config file to raise the precedence of Assamese:

```
$ cat ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/90-prefer-assamese.conf
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
        <alias>
                <family>serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Assamese</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>sans-serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Assamese</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
        <alias>
                <family>monospace</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lohit Assamese</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

It resulted in this:

```
$ fc-match -a | grep -i lohit
Lohit-Assamese.ttf: "Lohit Assamese" "Regular"
Lohit-Bengali.ttf: "Lohit Bengali" "Regular"
Lohit-Gujarati.ttf: "Lohit Gujarati" "Regular"
Lohit-Punjabi.ttf: "Lohit Punjabi" "Regular"
Lohit-Devanagari.ttf: "Lohit Devanagari" "Regular"
```

Comment: Worked but will the bengali characters would be looking different in this case as we have provided prefrence to assamese

Comment: @somyabhargava: Was that a question? Possibly; you tell me. :) If you have a need to view both Assamese and Bangla contents, it's possible to make the preferences locale dependent. Would that help?